# Pandas truncate incomplete time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple pandas df. I wish to extract data where monthly data is present. For example, for df

```
   PORTFOLIO       DATE  IRR
          A 2018-02-27  0.7
          A 2018-02-28  0.8
          A 2018-03-01  0.9
          A 2018-03-02  0.4
          A 2018-03-03  0.2
          A 2018-03-04  0.3
          A 2018-03-05  0.4
          A 2018-03-06  0.9
.
.
.
.
          A 2018-03-31  0.8
          A 2018-04-01  0.9
          A 2019-04-02  0.4
          A 2019-04-03  0.8
```

The output should be:

```
   PORTFOLIO       DATE  IRR
          A 2018-03-01  0.9
          A 2018-03-02  0.4
          A 2018-03-03  0.2
          A 2018-03-04  0.3
          A 2018-03-05  0.4
          A 2018-03-06  0.9
.
.
.
.
          A 2018-03-31  0.8
```

Is there any way to do this? Ideally I am able to do DATE>= 2018-03-01 and DATE<=2018-03-31. But, all my df have different dates so, hardcoding fails...

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to group the `DATE` column on `Year-Month` and `transform` using `count` to count the number of days, then use [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) + [`Series.dt.daysinmonth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.daysinmonth.html) to create a boolean mask and use this to filter the rows:

```
s = df['DATE'].groupby(df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).transform('count')
df = df[s.eq(df['DATE'].dt.daysinmonth)]
```

Result:

```
  PORTFOLIO        DATE  IRR
          A  2018-03-01  0.9
          A  2018-03-02  0.4
          A  2018-03-03  0.2
          A  2018-03-04  0.3
          .
          .
          .
          A  2018-03-31  0.8
```

Comment: @Graipher I think we need `transform` because we need to compare it with `daysinmonth` series so index of both the series need to match.

Comment: Ah, yes. It would only be the same if you had used `.agg('count')`...